# reconcile git svn after git filter-branch

Tags: git-svn, git-filter-branch

I am attempting to convert a SVN repository into git. The SVN repository is being actively used, while we work out the details of converting.

I followed all the guides and created an author mapping file and cloned the SVN repository.

`> git svn clone https://host/svn/Project --trunk=trunk -A svn-author-map.txt`

Concurrently with this switch to git, I would also like to atone for some of the sins of the SVN past (stored passwords, etc).  However as soon as I alter any of the history with `git filter-branch` or BFG, I seem to break the ability to incorporate any updates from SVN.

`> git svn fetch --fetch-all
fatal: Invalid revision range [sha from clone]..refs/remotes/trunk`

Is there a way to refresh the git-svn ids to the post filter-branch ids? Or is there no going back after changing any history?

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the history after conversion, then maintaining the link can become tricky.

I guess the best options are either do one-time conversion (make svn source read-only, fully switch to edited git repo), or just keep the history as is and change the leaked passwords instead.